# Show loader till ajax jquery function is busy executing, when async is set to false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to show loader till ajax jquery function is busy executing its line of codes, until now i have worked but i can't know when jquery function has fully completed it's execution when async is set to false. In below code i have added complete function section which gets executed far before ajax function has fully executed so its looks like the system has hanged up, so i need to show a loader till ajax function is executing. Please help to solve this issue.Thanks........

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: 'get_record.php',
    dataType:'json',
    async: false,
    success:function(result){
        var mainDiv = $('#main_outer');

        $.each(result, function(key,value) {
            var box_wrapper = $('<div>').addClass('boxwrapper').appendTo(mainDiv);
        });
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
         $('.loader').show();  
    },
    complete: function(){
        var everythingLoaded = setInterval(function() {
            clearInterval(everythingLoaded);
            setInterval(function () { $('.loader').hide(); }, 2500);  
        }, 10);
    }  
});
</script>
```

Comment: `async: false` should never be used as it is a terrible practice and is also being deprecated by browsers. You should be seeing warnings in console regarding this

Comment: `setInterval(... clearInterval(...) ...)` = `setTimeout(...)`: You should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.... and same as @charlietfl said. The system will hang up, because it is a synchronous request. remove `async: false`

Comment: If i do not use async:false, then sometimes ajax request does not load completely, thus element which i am dynamically creating in each loop is not created completely... so whats the alternative solution to it.

Comment: show us the code that creates these elements

Comment: Can't you add `$('.loader').hide()` to your `success:function(result){}` block? Or am I misunderstanding what your goal is?

Comment: actually the present condition is loader gets hide before my ajax function execution gets completed because of async:false, so i need to know a way to show user a loader till the complete execution of ajax code so that user does not see the hang up screen which is due to the async:false, Please help if you can to solve my problem or give any alternative soln......

Comment: I think you should put `$('.loader').hide()` after your `$.each(result..etc)` block. This will hide loading after it finished loading regardless of `async: true` or `async: false`. But you should definitely figure out a way to not use `async: false` as the others have said.

Comment: Can you please give some examples or link to examples how to work without async:false because if i load page very fastly then sometimes html elements does not get loaded properly.

Comment: You may need to put the entire AJAX call in a `$(document).ready(function() { //code here });` Without knowing the entire page it's hard to say why it may not load properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78942/discussion-between-user3653474-and-clark).